# awk: delete first and last entry of comma-separated field

Tags: awk

I have a 4 column data that looks something like the following:

```
 a    1    g    1,2,3,4,5,6,7
 b    2    g    3,5,3,2,6,4,3,2
 c    3    g    5,2,6,3,4
 d    4    g    1,5,3,6,4,7
```

I am trying to delete first two numbers and the last two numbers on entire fourth column so the output looks like the following

```
 a    1    g    3,4,5
 b    2    g    3,2,6,4
 c    3    g    6
 d    4    g    3,6
```

Can someone give me a help? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have a look at `split()` in the man page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$ awk '{n=split($4, a, ","); for (i=3; i<=n-2; i++) t=t""a[i](i==n-2?"":","); print $1, $2, $3, t; t=""}' file
a 1 g 3,4,5
b 2 g 3,2,6,4
c 3 g 6
d 4 g 3,6
```

#### Explanation

- `n=split($4, a, ",")` slices the 4th field in pieces, based on comma as delimiter. As `split()` returns the number of pieces we got, we store it in `n` to work with it later on.
- `for (i=3; i<=n-2; i++) t=t""a[i](i==n-2?"":",")` stores in `t` the last field, looping through all the slices.
- `print $1, $2, $3, t; t=""`  prints the new output and blanks the variable `t`.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for your posted sample input:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^([^,]+,){2}|(,[^,]+){2}$/,"",$NF)}1' file
a 1 g 3,4,5
b 2 g 3,2,6,4
c 3 g 6
d 4 g 3,6
```

If you have cases where there's less than 4 commas in your 4th field then update your question to show how those should be handled.

Comment: You should notice that using `gnu awk` you need version 4.x, or type `awk --re-interval 'code'` to make it work with 3.x

Comment: Good point but I'm really not sure if that's something that needs to be said or not. Certainly you should always state if a feature is specific to one type of awk (e.g. gawk or nawk or..) but when it's a POSIX feature common across most modern awks, do you need to say in what release of each modern awk the feature exists and how to enable it in each release of each awk? I lean towards "no" and just leave it up to the OP to tell us if it doesn't work for them in whatever awk/version they are currently using and then take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

This uses bash array manipulation. It may be a little ... gnarly:

```
while read -a fields; do                      # read the fields for each line
    IFS=, read -a values <<< "${fields[3]}"   # split the last field on comma
    new=("${values[@]:2:${#values[@]}-4}")    # drop the first 2 and last fields
    fields[3]=$(IFS=,; echo "${new[*]}")      # join the new list on comma
    printf "%s\t" "${fields[@]}"; echo        # print the new line
done <<END
 a    1    g    1,2,3,4,5,6,7
 b    2    g    3,5,3,2,6,4,3,2
 c    3    g    5,2,6,3,4
 d    4    g    1,5,3,6,4,7
END
```

```
a   1   g   3,4,5   
b   2   g   3,2,6,4 
c   3   g   6   
d   4   g   3,6
```